# Delaying animation

Tags: android, translate-animation

What I am looking to do is on button click, activate 3 TranslateAnimation

```
case R.id.button18Holes:

        //*********************************//
        //***LAUNCHES ACTUAL APPLICATION***//
        //*********************************//
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, -500, 0,0 );
        slide.setDuration(1000);   
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        buttonHelp.startAnimation(slide); <-- first
        button9Holes.startAnimation(slide); <-- should start slightly after first
        button18Holes.startAnimation(slide); <-- should start slightly after second

//This should wait until all animations are complete
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(src.getContext(), EasyPar.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        break;
```

Unsure of how to get that effect to slide the buttons off the screen one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running the animations after a set amount of time using [getTransformation(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#getTransformation%28long,%20android.view.animation.Transformation%29) or try waiting for each to end by polling the [hasEnded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#hasEnded%28%29) method of the preceding animation.

Comment: Thank you!  Did not see those :)